# How to allocate a non-constant sized array in Go

Tags: arrays, go

How do you allocate an array in Go with a run-time size?

The following code is illegal:

```
 n := 1
 var a [n]int
```

you get the message `prog.go:12: invalid array bound n` (or similar), whereas this works fine:

```
 const n = 1
 var a [n]int
```

The trouble is, I might not know the size of the array I want until run-time.

(By the way, I first looked in the question [How to implement resizable arrays in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387273/57171) for an answer, but that is a different question.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is you don't allocate an ***array*** directly, you get Go to allocate one for you *when creating a* ***slice***.

The built-in function `make([]T, length, capacity)` creates a slice *and the array behind it*, and there is no (silly) compile-time-constant-restriction on the values of `length` and `capacity`. As it says in the [Go language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> A slice created with `make` always allocates a new, hidden array to which the returned slice value refers.

So we can write:

```
 n := 12
 s := make([]int, n, 2*n)
```

and have an array allocated size `2*n`, with `s` a slice initialised to be the first half of it.

I'm not sure why Go doesn't allocate the array `[n]int` directly, given that you can do it indirectly, but the answer is clear:  "*In Go, use slices rather than arrays (most of the time).*"

Comment: Even the reflection package doesn't seem to permit allocating dynamic-sized arrays. I suspect this is related to the type system, since the array size is part of the type, so dynamic sizes would require dynamically generating new type IDs.

Comment: @Evan Yes, though I avoid using *dynamic* to describe this.  Strictly speaking the array size isn't dynamic: once it is created the array size is fixed.  I suppose this is related to the fact that you can't get at the array behind a slice.  If you could you could look at its type and this would have to be generated anew.  It makes some sort of sense.

Comment: I have accepted my own answer since it appears to be correct.