# How to allocate a non-constant sized 2D array in Go?

Tags: arrays, matrix, go

I want to allocate space for a 2 dimensional array and I want to do so in a clean way.

```
address [10]int
myLength := len(address)

// 1. but this not work at all
matrix := [myLength][myLength]byte

// 2. and this initializes 10 arrays with length 0
matrix := make([][]int, myLength, myLength)
```

I am getting an error for the first attempt:

> non-constant array bound l

PS not solved by: [How to allocate a non-constant sized array in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290858/how-to-allocate-a-non-constant-sized-array-in-go)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no "one liner" way to do that. simply do:

```
matrix := make([][]int, myLength)
for i : = 0; i < myLength; i++ {
   matrix[i] = make([]int, myLength)
}
```