# How to adjust the size of two-dimensional array in Go?

Tags: go

I have written a program that reads input lines and checks if a line begins with `#`.
If so, the current line and the next one will be saved in two columns in the same row in a two-dimensional array:

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vZ2kNrni9i)

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "strings"
)

func main() {
        const input = "#FooBar1\nFooBar1\n#Foobar2\nFooBar2\n#FooBar3\nFooBar3"

        var multiDimArr [3][2]string
        var lineCount int

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
        for line := 0; scanner.Scan(); line++ {
                if strings.HasPrefix(scanner.Text(), "#") {
                        multiDimArr[line][0] = scanner.Text()
                        scanner.Scan()
                        multiDimArr[line][1] = scanner.Text()
                        lineCount++
                }
        }
        for i := 0; i < lineCount; i++ {
                for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
                        fmt.Printf("multiDimArr[%d][%d] = %s\n", i, j, multiDimArr[i][j])
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
multiDimArr[0][0] = #FooBar1
multiDimArr[0][1] = FooBar1
multiDimArr[1][0] = #Foobar2
multiDimArr[1][1] = FooBar2
multiDimArr[2][0] = #FooBar3
multiDimArr[2][1] = FooBar3
```

My problem is that I need to know the number of lines in the input when building the program, so I can adjust the size of `multiDimArr`.

Can I do anything to make it take any number of lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement resizable arrays in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387273/how-to-implement-resizable-arrays-in-go)

Answer (score 2):

Try [this variation](https://play.golang.org/p/3c8IJ5SDwy):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const input = "#FooBar1\nFooBar1\n#Foobar2\nFooBar2\n#FooBar3\nFooBar3"

    var multiDimArr [][2]string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if strings.HasPrefix(scanner.Text(), "#") {
            firstLine := scanner.Text()
            scanner.Scan()
            secondLine := scanner.Text()
            multiDimArr = append(multiDimArr, [2]string{firstLine, secondLine})
        }
    }
    for i, row := range multiDimArr {
        for j, line := range row {
            fmt.Printf("multiDimArr[%d][%d] = %s\n", i, j, line)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Slice: `[][2]string{}` , so you don't need to count the number of lines of input:

Try this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "bufio"
import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    const input = "#FooBar1\nFooBar1\n#Foobar2\nFooBar2\n#FooBar3\nFooBar3"
    multiDimArr := [][2]string{}
    for i, r := 0, bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input)); r.Scan(); i++ {
        line1 := r.Text()
        if !strings.HasPrefix(line1, "#") || !r.Scan() {
            break
        }
        multiDimArr = append(multiDimArr, [2]string{line1, r.Text()})
    }
    fmt.Println(multiDimArr)
}
```

output:

```
[[#FooBar1 FooBar1] [#Foobar2 FooBar2] [#FooBar3 FooBar3]]
```

---

Also you may use this working sample code if you need to pre scan input to count the number of lines, using `multiDimArr := make([][2]string, n)` makes this slice  `[][2]string` with `length = capacity = n`:

```golang
package main

import "bufio"
import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    const input = "#FooBar1\nFooBar1\n#Foobar2\nFooBar2\n#FooBar3\nFooBar3"
    n := 0
    for r := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input)); r.Scan() && strings.HasPrefix(r.Text(), "#") && r.Scan(); n++ {
    }
    multiDimArr := make([][2]string, n)
    for i, r := 0, bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input)); r.Scan(); i++ {
        line1 := r.Text()
        if !strings.HasPrefix(line1, "#") || !r.Scan() {
            break
        }
        multiDimArr[i] = [2]string{line1, r.Text()}
    }
    fmt.Println(multiDimArr)
}
```

Output:

```
[[#FooBar1 FooBar1] [#Foobar2 FooBar2] [#FooBar3 FooBar3]]
```

---

[Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types):

> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a
>   non-negative [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type int.

So you can't use array because its length is constant, using `multiDimArr := [n][2]string{}` makes compile time error: `non-constant array bound n`:

```
n := preScan(input) 
//multiDimArr := [n][2]string{} // error: non-constant array bound n
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have much experience with Go yet. Are these two examples more or less effective and idiomatic compared to that posted by Amit Kumar Gupta?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes, the first sample code is similar to that post, except I checked the `r.Scan()` returns true or not, but he needs to check it ( in second `scanner.Scan()` he didn't (but should)), so if  the  second `scanner.Scan()`  returns false that code fails.